# Define $Tf(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$ Then, choose the correct option

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

$(C[0, 1], ||.||_{\infty})$ denotes the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ with $||f||_{\infty}$:=
$\sup{|f(t)|, t ∈ [0, 1]}$. For each $x \in [0, 1],$ define
$Tf(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$

Then, choose the correct option

$1.$ $T$ is injective but not surjective.

$2.$ $T$ is surjective but not injective.

$3.$ $T$ is bijective.

$4.$ $T$ is neither injective nor surjective.

My attempt  : i thinks  T is bijective  take  $f(x)= x$  option $3)$ will true

Is its True  ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: What is $T$? Is $T$ a function?

Comment: If $Tf=Tg$ then the function $h(x)=(Tf)(x)-(Tg)(x) =0$ for all $x\in (0,1),$  so for all $x\in (0,1)$ we have $f(x)-g(x)=(Tf)'(x)-(Tg)'(x)=h'(x)=0.$

Comment: @YiFan. $T$ is a function from $C[0,1]$ into $C[0,1]$ such that $T(f)(x)=\int_0^xf(t) dt$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$ and all $x\in [0,1].$  It is common in this topic to write $Tf$ for $T(f)$ and to write $Tf(x)$ for $T(f)(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g$ is a continuous function then it follows by the fundamental theorem of calculus that $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ is differentiable. Consider how this affects surjectivity.

A linear map, $T$ is injective if and only if $\ker T = \{0\}$. What can you conclude about $f$ if for every $x$

$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = 0$$

Hint apply fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: ..@Olof then which option is correct ?

Comment: What happens when you apply FTC to the integral equation above?

Comment: ..@Olof  $f(x)- f(0)= 0 $ , $f(x) = f(0)$ that mean   option $2$  is correct ?? is its  correct

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of differentiating both sides to obtain that $f(x) = 0$ and therefore the only element in the kernel is the zero function which implies injectivity. How do you come to the conclusion that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: take $f(x) =   a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2$   now  $T= \frac{1}{dx} \int_{0}^{x}{f(x)}$  this  implies surjectivity

Comment: For surjectivity you want to show that for every continuous function $g$ there exists some continuous function $f$ such that $Tf = g$. I fail to see how you reasoning implies surjectivity

Comment: then what is correct option   can u elaborate ur answeer

Comment: $Tf(x)$ is differentiable. If $T$ were surjective then that would mean that every continuous function $g$ could be written as $g = Tf$ but then this also implies that every continuous function is differentiable! Is that true? if not then $T$ is definitely not surjective. $T$ is injective by the reasoning i supplied above

Comment: To  the proposer: Let $g(x)=|x-1/2|.$ If $Tf=g$ then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $ f(1/2)=(Tf)'(1/2)=g'(1/2). $  But $g'(1/2)$ does not exist

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ maps from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$, $T$ is not surjective. For every $f$ we have $Tf(0)=0$, but not every function $g$ in $C[0,1]$ has $g(0)=0$. Hence not every $g\in C[0,1]$ is of the form $g=Tf$ for some $f\in C[0,1]$.

Comment: what is the correct option

Comment: The correct option is 1.

Comment: The correct option is 1., since by my answer above $T$ is not surjective and additionally $T$ is injective as Olof Rubin answered:
(more explicitely:) Since we have $(Tf)'(x)=f(x)$  (\*) by the fundamental theorem of calculus, it holds that if $Tf=0$, i. e. $Tf$ is the constant zero function, then $(Tf)'=0$ and hence $f=0$ by (\*). So $T$ is injective, because it is linear and the kernel is $\{0\}$.